# How to get user Id from username in facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I get Id of any user, using Graph-API Facebook, if I know only their username?

Comment: If you're wondering why you've been downvoted a lot it's most likely due to your question missing what you've tried and the code you've tried. Check out this [link](http://sscce.org/) for some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is impossible. You can´t use the username anymore, for privacy reasons. You only get a User ID by authorizing a User in your App. And you only get an App Scoped ID, not the real one.

Changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0